# Is "those who came in greatest numbers" grammatical?

Tags: adjectives, superlative-degree

I am studying English and I have a question.
I found it in my text book written by some teacher who is not a native speaker.

"Those who came first and in ***greatest numbers*** to make their homes on the eastern coast of North America were mostly from England."

I do understand the meaning of this sentence, but I cannot understand why the word 'greatest', Superlative adjective, is not accompanied by the word "the". 
Is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: Yes, it is grammatically correct.

Comment: Superlatives do not always require the definite article. Your example would work grammatically, either with or without.

Comment: The sentence would, nonetheless benefit from some punctuation - i.e. commas after *first*, *numbers*, and *America*.

Comment: @AbdurrhmanZaki (and the OP) should simply and politely be guided to http://ell.stackexchange.com/.